# Error on installing .apk file with version 2.1

Tags: android, android-emulator, apk, installation

I just worked my Android application with device (HTC Magic) version 1.5 and it loads properly and when i try to load the same application  with the other phone by installing the .apk file of version1.5 with android version 2.1  and kernel version 2.6.29 omap1 but now i couldnt find my application getting installed on my device...

I have sent a link to view the screenshot for error http://img137.imageshack.us/img137/6411/img0981jw.jpg.
In the screenshot you can see Quadmon icon on top and it says it can not install app in Korean.

I have just followed the instructions given in this link  (http://www.waxworlds.org/edam/software/android/how-to-install-an-apk-on-your-android-device) to install .apk file into my htc magic phone.

Is there any other way to get distributed my apk file into the device?

Answer (score 0):

Look here :) : http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html